# Laravel 4.2 route Redirect not working properly

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4, routes

In my `LoginController` I have

```
return Redirect::route('admin.login.index')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

But instead of redirecting me to

```
http://site_corporate/admin/login
```

it redirects to

```
http://site_corporate/http://site_corporate/admin/login
```

This one works as expected:

```
return Redirect::to('admin/login')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

but I want to use named routes instead of this.

Comment: Have you created the Route itself? [Check](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) for Named Routes documentation.

Comment: Of course created. And it works if I use, e.g. `<a href="{{ route('admin.login.index') }}">Admin login</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you have an underscore in your domain name, which makes it effectively an invalid domain according to the Laravel implementation. It has once been logged as a bug in Laravel (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2511).

To solve this, you should remove the underscore from your domain name.